# how can i divide numeric elements in an array while keeping the values of non-numeric ones

Tags: javascript, arrays

given this array ['1', 23, null, 46.5, '34e2', , false, 'true', , 40], how can i divide the numeric elements in it by 10, but also keeping the non numeric elements in it, without modifying those values.
what i did so far is this:

```
var divide = numbers.map(function(x){
    if(typeof x === 'number' && isFinite(x)){
    return x / 10;
    }
});

console.log(divide); // [undefined, 2.3, undefined, 4.65, undefined, 6: undefined, 7: undefined, 9: 4]
```

Comment: you're only returning in the if statement...just add an else return x

Answer (score 3):

Your mapping function has to **return a value for each of the elements, not only the numeric ones**:

```
var divide = numbers.map(function(x){
    if(typeof x === 'number' && isFinite(x)){
        return x / 10;
    } else return x;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Array.prototype.map()` will return a value from the anonymous function performed on each iteration over the Array, and without a specific value to be returned it will – as will any JavaScript function – simply return `undefined` if a specific value isn't provided to be returned (as you found out); so the key is to return the current value if that value doesn't match the conditions of the `if` assessment.

```js
var numbers = ['1', 23, null, 46.5, '34e2', , false, 'true', , 40],
  divide = numbers.map(function(x) {
    if ('string' === typeof x && isFinite(x)) {
      return x / 10;
    } else {
      return x;
    }
  });

console.log(divide);
```

Incidentally, as you're not using `this` anywhere, and if ES6` is an option for you, and your users, you could also use Arrow functions:

```js
var numbers = ['1', 23, null, 46.5, '34e2', , false, 'true', , 40],
  divide = numbers.map(x => 'string' === typeof x && isFinite(x) ? x/10 : x);

console.log(divide);
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 2):

You are returning the the numerical value but you are not handling the case if `x` isn't a number just add `return x` after the if condition and it would work perfectly :)

```
var divide = numbers.map(function(x){
    if(typeof x === 'number' && isFinite(x)){
      return x / 10;
    }
    return x;
});
```